# jQuery Deferred vs jqXHR

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

I use:

```
var jqXHR = $.ajax(settings);
jqXHR.success(function(result){});
jqXHR.error(function(result){});
jqXHR.complete(function(result){});
```

But version 1.5 has added the deferred object.

Q: In general, when do you use success, error and complete methods vs. the new hotness of deferred then, done and fail?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For `$.ajax()` and family `.success` is merely a synonym for Deferred's `.done`, and likewise `.error` is a synonym for `.fail`.

So in fact the examples you show are *already* deferred methods, but with different names.

`.complete` is *mostly* a synonym for the new jQuery 1.6 `.always`, and you can get the same effect using `$.then(cb, cb)`, which will cause `cb` to be invoked whether the AJAX call succeeds or not.  I believe there are minor differences in which parameters are passed to the "fail" callbacks between the `.complete`, `.always` and `$.then` variants.

I personally prefer to use the Deferred version of those named functions, because then you don't need to worry about whether your deferred objects are jqXHRs or not.  Only `jqXHRs` have `.success`, `.error`, and `.complete`, but *every* Deferred (including jqXHRs) has `.done`, `.fail` and `.always`.

**EDIT** it seems the jQuery devs agree with me - they've [announced](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) that `.success`, `.error` and `.complete` will be deprecated in jQuery 1.8

Answer (score 9):

Deferred is meant to replace jqXHR and abstracts the idea of success and error beyond ajax.

A quick look at the source code: jQuery 1.6.1

```
// completeDeferred is resolved in only one place.
completeDeferred.resolveWith( callbackContext, [ jqXHR, statusText ] );

deferred.promise( jqXHR ); // this attaches the promise methods to jqXHR
jqXHR.success = jqXHR.done;
jqXHR.error = jqXHR.fail;
jqXHR.complete = completeDeferred.done;
```

I made a cheese [slide show](https://docs.google.com/present/view?id=dpr5j57_16fpvxznfh) for work about how deferred is useful.

Comment: Great slide show and new concepts.  What's the simplest way to implement promises/deferred if you don't have jQuery?

Comment: Simple version https://github.com/kriszyp/node-promise Another implementation that wraps XHR request. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rbuckton/archive/2011/08/15/promise-js-2-0-promise-framework-for-javascript.aspx

Comment: You've have a typo several times where you've misspelled the word function.