# Catching errors thrown from nested asynchronous functions at the top-level

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, async-await

I am having trouble "catching" an error using either a try/catch or `.catch` statement, and I believe it is because the error is not being thrown in a "conventional" manner. At the top-level, I have an invocation of a function within an async function:

```js
async function main() {
    let computedValue;
    try {
      computedValue = await module.doComputation();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("We caught the error!")
      computedValue = null;
    }
}
```

```js
// in `module`
import $ from 'jquery';

export function doComputation() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: location.href,
      success: (data) => {
        const text = $($.parseHTML(data)).find('#some-dom-element').text()
        const total = text.match(/[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?/g)[0]; // this line throws an error!
        if (total > 0) {
          resolve(total);
        }
      },
      error: () => {
        resolve(-1);
      },
    });
  });
}
```

When I run this, the exception that is thrown from within `doComputation` is unhandled, and it looks like:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '0')`

I am not particularly surprised that this function threw an error (and I understand why), however I need to be sure that `main` can safely catch the error that this function throws.

Importantly, I would really prefer to be able to catch this error at the level of `main` (technically there are hundreds of different implementations of `doComputation` in my project and having to modify all of them would be a tad difficult).

Does anyone have any ideas about how I might solve this problem? Adding a `.catch` to `await module.doComputation` does not seem to do the trick and also makes my LSP unhappy.

I tried adding a `.catch` statement to the offending line, and also wrapping the entire statement in a try/catch, but to no avail.

Comment: [Don't use `success` and `error` callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6285407/1048572). Use `$.ajax({type:…, url:…}).then()` - or even just `const data = await $.ajax(…)`. [Don't use `new Promise`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31327725/1048572).

Comment: You could use `reject` instead of `resolve` on the error function.

Answer (score -1):

You should include a `reject` variable in your promise and handle the error that way

```
return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: location.href,
  success: (data) => {
    const text = $($.parseHTML(data)).find('#some-dom-element').text()
    const total = text.match(/[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?/g)[0]; // this line throws an error!
    if (total > 0) {
      resolve(total);
    }
  },
  error: () => {
    reject(-1)
  },
  });
 });
}
```

And in main

```
function main() {
let computedValue;

  module.doComputation().then((res) => {
      computedValue = res
  }).catch(()=>{
     console.log("We caught the error!")
     computedValue = null;
  })
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! This will help. Is there any way I can catch the error without modifying `doComputation`?

Comment: To throw an error you need to use the reject method provided from Promise object but you probably should listen to @Bergi I'm also fairly new to Javascript.